# Dispose/Remove component using hooks

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

> I'm writing a form for registering a new user, my desire is that when the `registerNewUser`(POST method) returns 
>   200 status it should also dispose/remove the form method and and expose a new component saying, 'thank you' or such. 
>  
>   **1. How can I dispose my form component when getting a 200 status?** 
>   **2. And how can i make a new component appear?**

**Return**

```
 return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="registerAccountContainer">
            <input type="email"     placeholder="Email"     required onChange={handleChange('email')}/>
            <input type="password"  placeholder="Password"  required onChange={handleChange('password')}/>   
        <button type="submit"> Register Account </button>
    </form>
    )
```

**handleSubmit**

```
     const handleSubmit = event => {
        registerNewUser(user);
        event.preventDefault();
     }
```

**registerNewUser**

```
      export const registerNewUser = (user) => { Axios.post('http://localhost:8080/register', user)
      .then(function (response) {
        return alert("We've sent you mail! Please confirm your user.");
       /* THIS IS WHERE I WANT IT TO DISPOSE THE FORM COMPONENT AND
          REPLACE IT WITH A NEW SIMPLE <P>'THANK YOU'</P> */
       })
       .catch(function (error) {
         return alert(error);
       });
     }
```

Any suggestions on how i can solve this are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you need to declare a new variable in your local state and change it when the user is registered

```
state = { registered : false }

export const registerNewUser = (user) => { Axios.post('http://localhost:8080/register', user)
  .then(function (response) {
    this.setState({registered: true})
    return alert("We've sent you mail! Please confirm your user.");
   })
   .catch(function (error) {
     return alert(error);
   });
 }
```

and check if the state is changed you'll change a label

```
return ({this.state.registered ? <p>'THANK YOU'</p> :
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="registerAccountContainer">
        <input type="email"     placeholder="Email"     required onChange={handleChange('email')}/>
        <input type="password"  placeholder="Password"  required onChange={handleChange('password')}/>   
    <button type="submit"> Register Account </button>
</form>}
)
```